# How to create a Joomla Subtitle using "|" Vertical Bar?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have seen some templates in Joomla that allow you to create a subtitle for an article just by entering the text into a single title text field such as this...

```
The Article Title | And My Subtitle
```

It doesn't seem to be a custom field - it appears more like it might be a shortcode. Has anybody come across this before and know where I can find the code for this or where in such templates I should look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do this in a template override. Anywhere the title field might display, you would want to do something like this in the code before the title display part -

```
<?php
$titleparts = explode("|",$this->item->title);
$this->item->title = $titleparts[0];
$subtitle =  $titleparts[1];
?>
```

You would probably want to put in a conditional statement looking for the | in the title before processing it, but you get the idea.

WARNING - I didn't test this code but it should work.

Comment: That's awesome thanks very much I will test it out and post the results here.